# iMac 27" WiFi networking issues

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, imac

I have a 27" iMac (OS X 10.6.4) which has suddenly developed a heap of networking issues.

It's dropping in and out all of the time and seems to get confused about whether it's connected or not.

Is this an issue I can fix or just a 'Mac' thing? My 6 other Windows PCs (and my iPhone) all work with the WiFi no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your PCs and iPhone are working, it would make sense that it's the local machine. If you insert your OS X install disc, you can try to connect to the wireless network from within the install CD (on the menu bar; don't know if the Snow Leopard install disc still has that feature or not). You could always try performing an *archive & install*, which would almost certainly rectify the problem if it's a software problem. If either of those fail, then it's a hardware problem, and I would take it in to a local Apple Store, or call Applecare.

Comment: Just to clairify, I'm almost certain the Snow Leopard install disk has the wireless menu bar item.